# Interact with background task with commands in submodule [discord.py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-asyncio, discord.py

I have a Discord bot written with the *non-rewrite* version of discord.py that sends a heartbeat-like message (among other things). I don't know if I understood it correctly but from tests, I found out that I need to have the `async def heartbeat()` function in the `main.py` file.

Excerpt from `main.py` (heartbeat works as intended):

```
[...]
import asyncio
import datetime
from configparser import ConfigParser

startup_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
[...]

async def heartbeat():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

    heartbeat_config = ConfigParser()
    heartbeat_config.read('./config/config.ini')
    hb_freq = int(heartbeat_config.get('Heartbeat', 'hb_freq'))  # frequency of heartbeat message
    hb_channel = heartbeat_config.get('Heartbeat', 'hb_channel')  # target channel of heartbeat message
    hb_channel = bot.get_channel(hb_channel)  # get channel from bot's channels

    await bot.send_message(hb_channel, "Starting up at: `" + str(startup_time) + "`")
    await asyncio.sleep(hb_freq)  # sleep for hb_freq seconds before entering loop
    while not bot.is_closed:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()  # time right now
        tdelta = now - startup_time  # time since startup
        tdelta = tdelta - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=tdelta.microseconds)  # remove microseconds from tdelta
        beat = await bot.send_message(hb_channel, "Still running\nSince: `" + str(startup_time) + "`.\nCurrent uptime: `" + str(tdelta))
        await asyncio.sleep(hb_freq)  # sleep for hb_freq seconds before initialising next beat
        await bot.delete_message(beat)  # delete old beat so it can be replaced

[...]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    global heartbeat_task
    heartbeat_task = bot.loop.create_task(heartbeat())  # creates heartbeat task in the background
    bot.run(token)  # run bot
```

I have some commands that are supposed to interact with the created `heartbeat_task`, but they are in a different module, called `dev.py` (residing in the same directory as `main.py`).

Excerpt from `dev.py`:

```
[...]
from main import heartbeat_task, heartbeat
[...]
@commands.group(pass_context=True)
async def heart(self, ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        return

@heart.command(pass_context=True)
async def stop(self, ctx):
    # should cancel the task from main.py
    heartbeat_task.cancel()
    await self.bot.say('Heartbeat stopped by user {}'.format(ctx.message.author.name))

@heart.command(pass_context=True)
async def start(self, ctx):
    # start the heartbeat if it is not running
    global heartbeat_task
    if heartbeat_task.cancelled():
        heartbeat_task = self.bot.loop.create_task(heartbeat())
        await self.bot.say('Heartbeat started by user {}'.format(ctx.message.author.name))
    else:
        return
[...]
```

These commands work perfectly fine when they are part of `main.py` (with the necessary adjustments of course, like removing `self`, the import, etc), but since I want all developer related commands to go into a module of their own, so I tried moving them.

I get the following error when I try to load the module:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'heartbeat_task'.`

Removing that import from `dev.py` leads to a successful loading of the module, but upon using either of the commands, the console throws an error:

`NameError: name 'heartbeat_task' is not defined`

Which traces back to the line `heartbeat_task.cancel()` (in the case of `heart stop` // `if heartbeat_task.cancelled():` (in the case of `heart start`).

Now my question.
How can I have the async `heartbeat()` in `main.py` but influence the task with the commands in the `dev.py` module?

And if I can't, what are feasible alternatives that keep the commands in `dev.py` (the function itself doesn't need to stay in `main.py` but is preferred to stay there)?

(I have searched for quite some time and couldn't find a problem like mine or a solution that happened to work for me too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to have a background task in a cog is to add an `on_ready` coroutine to the cog that will kick off the background task, instead of starting it manually:

```
class MyCog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def heartbeat(self):
        ...

    async def on_ready(self):
        self.heartbeat_task = self.bot.loop.create_task(heartbeat())

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        self.heartbeat_task.cancel()
        await self.bot.say('Heartbeat stopped by user {}'.format(ctx.message.author.name))


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

Note that you don't need to decorate `on_ready` with anything in the cog, the `add_cog` machinery will pick it up based on its name.